# Making 1 image go between two other images?

Tags: position, z-index, background-image

At my [site](http://mmd3e12dae42.keaweb.dk/test/index.html) on the first page i have two images put together so it looks like a sunset. I want to my logo to go down between them as if it was the sun, but i cant make this happend. The logo is currently at the second page of the site
Heres i the html:

```
<div id="intro">
     <div id="introbaggrundbagved"></div>
     <a name="section1" class="section">SECTION 1</a>
     <div id="logo">
     </div>
</div> <!--#intro-->
```

And the css:

```
#intro{
  background: url('images/introforan.png') no-repeat center;
  height: 900px;
  margin: 0;
  position: relative;
  z-index: 3;
}

#introbaggrundbagved{
    background: url('images/introbagved.png') no-repeat center;
    height: 900px;
    width: 1440;
    margin:0;   
    position: relative;
}

#logo{
    background: transparent url('images/logo.png') no-repeat center;
    width: 600px;
    height: 600px;
    position: relative;
    margin-left: 420px;
    margin-top: 100px;
    z-index: 2;
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to take the `#logo` div out of its parent element `#intro`and give it a z-index that is larger than both of its siblings— then wrap all of the `header` elements into an `#intro-wrapper` div. In addition, I would then `position` the `#logo` element using `position: absolute`, instead of `relative`, this will give you more granular control on it's placement without disturbing the document flow of the surrounding elements.

Also, it appears that you have the function `parallaxScroll` updating the `top` property of `#logo`, which will prevent the element from being placed between your two images.

```
    function parallaxScroll(){
      var scrolledY = $(window).scrollTop();
      $('#logo').css('top','+'+((scrolledY*.376))+'px');
        ....
      }
```

Comment: I did this now and i got the logo into the right spot. But i need the logo to go between the 2 images you see in the front page. The grass and sky is 2 different images. The image in #intro should be in front, the image in #logo ind the middle and the image in #introbaggrundbagved should be behind.
Thx for helping me out :)

Comment: Well the idea was to make it go down like the sun between the 2 images when people scroll down the page.

Comment: Give `introbaggrundbagved` a z-index of 1, make sure `introbaggrundbagved` has a `height` property set.

Comment: I haven't looked at the function, but that's not the way it would work with your current set-up. You need to give the `container` element a `relative` position and then set its `overflow: hidden`, but you will need a pixel height value on the `container ` element to achieve this.

Comment: YES! Thanks a lot for the help :) I don't know why but the background image in introbaggrundbagved was impossible to get behind the logo so i put it into the container and it works fine. You can see it at the site now :) So now i just have to make the logo appear right away instead of when you start scrolling :P